# What is the exact meaning of defining `int *p={1,2,3};`?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to learn pointers in c.

As per my understanding `int *p={1,2,3};` defines a pointer to the array of integers i.e `{1,2,3}`. So I deduct that `p[0]` is the first element of this array i.e `1`. But my compiler(dev c++) is not giving any value and hanging for output.

How to find other elements of this array i.e `2` and `3` in terms of `p`? i.e is there any way to get these value through the pointer variable p. Please guide.

Sample program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

main()
{
    int *p={1,2,3};

    printf("%d\n",p[0]);

    getch();
}
```

**Update**: What about

```
int (*p)[3]={1,2,3};
```

Comment: Your compiler didn't produce any warnings when compiling this code?

Comment: The updated code is also illegal. Please don't edit your code to change the question, as it makes all the existing answers look strange to someone seeing the question for the first time. Instead, post an update, or a new question.

Answer (score 7):

```
int *p={1,2,3};
```

it is invalid C code. The right of `=` has to be a value of pointer type, not an initializer list of `int` elements.

Please enable all your compiler warnings and fix them.

```
int p[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

is valid C code. It initializes an array of `3` `int` elements.

Comment: Also legal is `int *p = (int []){1, 2, 3};`

Comment: Compiles fine in pre-C99, though. There are occasions where this can be perfectly valid usage, e.g. when need to store the actual memory addresses.

Comment: int (*p)[3]={1,2,3}; is valid right? My question was for that. I am updating question, please excuse me for mistake.

Comment: No that's not legal either

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    int a[] = {1,2,3};
    //int *p={1,2,3};//invalid
    int *p1=(int[]){1,2,3};//valid in C99
    printf("%d\n", p1[0]);//1
    p1=a;
    printf("%d\n", p1[0]);//1

    //int (*p)[3]={1,2,3};//invalid
    int (*p2)[3]=&(int[]){1,2,3};//valid in C99
    printf("%d\n", (*p2)[0]);//1
    p2 = &a;
    printf("%d\n", (*p2)[0]);//1

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,`int (*p)[3]` means pointer to array of 3 integers(My instructer also refers it as 2-dimensional pointer), in simple words it means that it can store address of the 1st row of a 2-Dimensional array,As you go on Increment the `p` it will point to the next subsequent row of the 2-D array, As demonstrated in below example.

```
int main(void)
{
    int ary[2][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    int (*p)[3]=ary;

    printf("using ary: %d %d\n",p[0],p[1]);    // outputs:2686708 2686720
    printf("using ptr: %d %d\n",ary[0],ary[1]); //outputs:2686708 2686720
    return 0;
}
```

And i think you are forgetting the basic property of pointers,They are used to store the address of other variables,You can't initialize pointers as you did in example,That is applicable only for strings,I feel you are trying to initialize integers pointers in the way of strings.

```
char *ptr="hello";         //correct 
char *ptr[]={"hi","bye" } // correct
int *pttr=123;            //Not Correct 
int *pttr[]={{123},{456}} //Not Correct
```